# Getting a value within the parent element of a clicked button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to Jquery and I'm trying to access the parent of a clicked button. This is due to the fact that I am generating divs dynamically, so I want the respective button click to apply to the correct div.

After accessing the parent of the clicked button, I want to access several input values within it.
I'm getting an error in the console :`[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #quantity` because I have a for loop that produces similar divs with a unique quantity.

I have tried using `document.getElementById("onekg").value;` But it only works for the first element and not subsequent elements.

```
    <% cakes.forEach(cake => { %>
        <div class="item-cart">
         <input type="hidden" name="onekg" id="onekg" value="1000">
         <input id="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="1">
         <button id="plus_btn" class="plus-btn qbtn" type="button" name="button">+</button>
       </div>
    <% }) %>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".plus-btn").click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  var currentItem = $(event.target).parents('.item-cart');
  console.log(currentItem);
  var onekg = document.getElementById("onekg").value;
  var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
  console.log(quantity + onekg)
})
```

I don't know if I'm thinking about this all wrong but I have tried several solutions without any success.

Comment: `id`s must be unique within the document, you've to give an unique id to the elements, or perhaps use a class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
$(".plus-btn").click(function (event) {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.item-cart');
});
```

The above code will find the item-cart class that is the parent of the button click. So on each click of the button, you can access the parent of that particular clicked button.

So your code would be something like below as per your code.

```
$(".plus-btn").click(function (event) {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.item-cart');
    var onekg = parent.find("#onekg").val();
    var quantity = parent.find("#quantity").val();
});
```

But you should be aware that there should not be any Id more than once in a page. So i would suggest you to change **onekg** and **quantity** to class and **rewrite** the code as following

```
<input type="hidden" name="onekg" class="onekg" value="1000">
<input class="quantity" type="text" name="quantity" value="1">
```

and **change your jQuery code to the following**.

```
$(".plus-btn").click(function (event) {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.item-cart');
    var onekg = parent.find(".onekg").val();
    var quantity = parent.find(".quantity").val();
});
```

Comment: how do I access the elements inside it?

Comment: Thank You very much! Saved me a lot of headache

Comment: @TimMwaura Happy to help :) Change the ID of the input fields to class or you will have to deal with more issues later including HTML validation

Comment: `parent()` would be better than `closest()` in this situation.

Comment: @meleyal *"parent() would be better than closest() in this situation"* why so?

Comment: Because `closest()` will first check siblings, which is not needed here.

Comment: @meleyal Does closest() check siblings ? Won't it check only the element itself and the ancestors ?

Comment: @meleyal that's not correct. Please read the DOCS. https://api.jquery.com/closest/  It checks the emenet it-self and ancestors. As Melvin pointed out. Since it's such a great method it was introduced even natively in JS with `Element.closest()`

Comment: @melvin yes, after reading the docs it turns out you're right! However `parent()` in this case would only need to check a single element, while `closest()` would check both the element itself and the parent.

Comment: One last clarification.. Will currentItem.find('.item-cart')  be able to return the html? I am trying to console.log it but it appears as an object @melvin

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `Node.parentElement` is also great :P

Comment: @TimMwaura If you need the html content, then you need to use `find('.item-cart').html();`. As you said, currentItem.find('.item-cart') would return the object which you can use for element reference.

Comment: @melvin How can I pass a reference to that item. I'm trying to replace that html with some other html but I am unable to   ``` $(this).closest('.item-cart').html().replaceWith(` <div class="item-cart"> Hey there </div>`);```

Comment: no. You can set and get html using the same `.html()` of method. So here it would be  `$(this).closest('.item-cart').html(' <div class="item-cart"> ');`

Comment: @meleyal Ya. Looks like `parent()` is better in this situation.